# Batch Geocoding in R over daily limit with pay as you go?

Tags: r, geocoding, google-maps-api, ggmap

I have found the the geocode function in ggmap to be very helpful in the past.  Now I am trying to geocode about 60,000 addresses. The google maps API daily limit is 2500.  Google offers a "pay as you go" service that increases daily limits.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits

Here is my question:

Is there a way to access a "pay as you go" project through the ggmap geocode function (or something similar)?  If so, how would you do that?  That is:  how to use R's "geocode" for batch geocoding where you are willing to pay to go beyond the daily limit?

Comment: Are you asking how to use R with the specific service you mentioned, or just any large volume service?